# Nav Bar Positioning Using fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

My app uses fullPage.js. In order to get my nav bar to work after scrolling, I had to add this snippet of code in the  section of my html:

```
<style>
    header{
        position: fixed;
        z-index:1;
    }

</style>
```

Without it, when I scrolled down, the buttons/links in my nav bar were unclickable. Unfortunately with this addition of code, the arrangement of my nav bar is completely out of whack. Is there anything I can do so that "position fixed" doesn't ruin my arrangement?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Columbia Ride Share</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        });
    </script>
<style>
    header{
        position: fixed;
        z-index:1;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
  <header> 
       <h1 class = "page-title">Columbia Ride Share</h1>
       <nav>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#top">home</a></li>
               <li><button class="btn btn-link" onclick = "document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'"style="width:auto;">CREATE A RIDE</button></a></li>
               <div id="id02" class="modal">
                  <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                      <div class="imgcontainer">
                           <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class = "loginMsg">
                      <p>Where are you headed?<p>
                          <a href="create-a-ride-to-airport.html">I need a ride to the airport</a>
                          <a href="create-a-ride-from-airport.html">I need a ride to campus</a>
                      </div>
                   </form>
               </div>

               <li class = "login">
                   <button onclick = "document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"style="width:auto;">LOGIN</button>
               </li>
               <div id="id01" class="modal">
                   <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                       <div class="imgcontainer">
                           <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                            </div>
                           <div class="loginMsg">
                               <p>hi there!</p>
                               <p>log in to post and comment on columbia ride share</p>
                           </div> 
                           <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">connect with facebook</button>
               <button onclick = "googleSignin()" class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">connect with google     </button>
                    </form>
               </div>

           </ul>
       </nav>
  </header>
  <div id ="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class = "JFK">
            <h6>JFK</h6>
               <p> <a href = "toJFK.html">to</a>
                   <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "Newark">
           <h6>NEWARK</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "bottomRow">
           <h6>LAGUARDIA</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
           <div class = "createRide">
              <button class = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'"style="width:auto;">CREATE A RIDE</button>
           </div>    
           <div id="id02" class="modal">
           <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
               <div class="imgcontainer">
                       <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                   </div>
           <div class = "loginMsg">
                       <p>Where are you headed?<p>
                           <a href="create-a-ride-to-airport.html">I need a ride to the airport</a>
                           <a href="create-a-ride-from-airport.html">I need a ride to campus</a>
                    </div>
        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          <div class="section" id="section1"> 
          <div class = "welcome">
               <div class = "intro">
                   <p>Lorem ipsum elementum libero curae nam in id maecenas per, inceptos dui a aliquam velit eu ullamcorper ultricies platea, nibh adipiscing pulvinar nunc justo taciti non magna interdum lectus ligula cursus ornare aenean lacus tincidunt, semper gravida bibendum vitae laoreet morbi pharetra, nunc tellus donec imperdiet cubilia consectetur.Suscipit fermentum euismod etiam facilisis metus quam litora blandit himenaeos, convallis placerat felis mollis aliquam ante fringilla morbi tincidunt, at curabitur ligula sapien iaculis risus nullam platea morbi cursus adipiscing aliquet tempor commodo quis leo metus sem dictum.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAIY9XOb5QVDTxJKxtvSZRiyqgpGasHF3M",
    authDomain: "columbia-ride-share.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://columbia-ride-share.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "columbia-ride-share.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1058399238109"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

</script>
<script src = "app.js"></script>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
    var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
        jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
    }else{
        jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
</script>
<script> 
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

window.onclick= function(event){

    if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>  
      window.onload = function() {
         initApp();
      };
</script>
<script>
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

My css code is:

```
a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
}
body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: #c4d8e2;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", Helvetica Neue, serif;
}


.page-title {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: -5%;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: lighter;  
    margin-left:5%;
    line-height:35%;
}

.container {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.Newark {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    left: 35%;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: -14%; 
    background-image: url(chelsea.jpg);
    background-size: 301px 301px;
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}

.Newark h6{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;

}


.Newark p{
    position: relative;
    top: -170px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

.Newark p a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
    top: -30px;
}


.Newark:hover p {
    display: block;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
}

.Newark:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}


.JFK {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    left: 35%;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: -14%; 
    background-image: url(brooklyn.jpg);
    background-size: 301px 301px;
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}

.JFK h6{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;

}


.JFK p{
    position: relative;
    top: -170px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

.JFK p a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
    top: -30px;
}


.JFK:hover p {
    display: block;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
}

.JFK:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}

.bottomRow {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    left: 35%;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-image: url(nyu2.jpg);
    background-size: 301px 401px;
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    border-top: 1px white;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}

.bottomRow button{
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 110px 89px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    font-size:33px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight:700;
}


.bottomRow h6{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
}


.bottomRow p{
    position: relative;
    top: -170px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

.bottomRow p a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
    top: -30px;
}


.bottomRow:hover p {
    display: block;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
}

.bottomRow:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}


.createRide {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    left: 35%;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-image: url(train.jpg);
    background-size: 401px 301px;
    background-position: 300px 300px
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    border-top: 1px white;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}

.createRide button{
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 110px 89px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    font-size:33px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight:700;
}


.createRide h6{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
}


.createRide p{
    position: relative;
    top: -170px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

.createRide p a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
    top: -30px;
}


.createRide:hover p {
    display: block;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
}

.createRide:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}




/*Navigation Bar*/ 
nav ul {
   display: inline;
}

nav li{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline; 
  position: relative;
  left: 63.5%;
  top: -45px;
  font-variant: small-caps; 
  font-weight: 500;
}
nav li a{
    text-decoration:none;

}
.loginMsg{
    display: relative;
    margin-top: 25%;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: black;
}

.loginMsg p{

     text-align: center;
}
.loginMsg a{
    display:block;
    margin-top:13px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5px auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    border: 12px solid #888;
    border-color: #c4d8e2;
    width: 30%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    height: 60%;

}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    /* Position it in the top right corner outside of the modal */
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0; 
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Close button on hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Shared */
.loginBtn {
  padding: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 13em;  - apply for fixed size 
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: small-caps; 
  top: 10%; 
  left: 20%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}
.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}


/* Facebook */
.loginBtn--facebook {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4C69BA;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4C69BA, #3B55A0);
  font-family: "Helvetica neue", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354C8C;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:before {
  border-right: #364e92 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_facebook.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:hover,
.loginBtn--facebook:focus {
  background-color: #5B7BD5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5B7BD5, #4864B1);
}


/* Google */
.loginBtn--google {
  font-family: "Roboto", Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
  background: #DD4B39;
  display: block; 
}
.loginBtn--google:before {
  border-right: #BB3F30 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_google.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--google:hover,
.loginBtn--google:focus {
  background: #E74B37;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

.instructions{
    position: relative;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top: 50%;
    font-size: 36px;
}

button {
    background: none; 
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", Helvetica Neue, serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 500;    
    color: #c4d8e2;
}

button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.welcome{
   background-color: #c4d8e2;
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   margin-top:-3%;
   max-width: 100%;
   float:left;
   clear: left;

}
.intro{
   margin-left:10%;
   display: block;
}

.intro p{
    color:white;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: perhaps a z-index issue ... the navbar is "under" the content

Comment: also the css `#header` selects an element with `id="header` - which you don't have - you should use `header {...` however it already seems to be "fixed" ... so, remove #, remove position, and add `z-index:1` - could fix it I guess

Comment: @JaromandaX no luck

Comment: put the `position:fixed` back :p along with the `z-index`

Comment: @JaromandaX that allows me to click the buttons, but now the placement is all out of whack..How do I get the buttons to stay where I originally designed the nav bar to be?

Comment: no idea as the code you've presented does show your css, or your js

Comment: that's a good point - my js doesn't do any styling for my index page, but I have included now my css

Comment: I meant doesn't, not does show :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to access the nav bar by setting the header's z-index to 1. The z-index specifies the stack of an element, so by setting it to 1, I was able to put it "in front" of the "section1" div. But I also had to set the position of the header, if I chose absolute, then it completely ruined all of the relative values that I had given it in my css file. By setting it to relative, I was able to preserve the arrangement I intended in my css file.

```
<style>
    header{
        position: relative;
        z-index:1;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: This does answer my question.